# Como alternar entre abas dentro de um modal bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css

estou trabalhando com bootstrap para fazer um modal de chat. A ideia seria a seguinte: Eu abro o modal onde está localizado o chat do usuário e na primeira aba do modal estaria um conteúdo (últimas mensagens, coisa do tipo) e na outra aba dentro do mesmo modal, estariam os contatos dos quais eu poderia iniciar uma nova conversa. Eu pretendo alternar as abas por meio do botão "MENSAGENS" e "NOVA CONVERSA", localizados na parte superior (não sei nem se devo usar button ou a ou input, sei la...) Desde já agradeço a ajuda!

[image: Não liguem para as cores... coloco-as para me localizar...]

Comment: Seria bom você disponibilizar o código para vermos o que já tentou.

Comment: Tem de indicar que versão do bootstrap está a usar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei que versão do **Bootstrap** está a usar, no exemplo a versão é a `4.3.1`

Tem duas tabs, uma de **Upload** e outra de **Browse**.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch demo modal</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>

                </button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div role="tabpanel">
                    <!-- Nav tabs -->
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#uploadTab" aria-controls="uploadTab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Upload</a>

                        </li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#browseTab" aria-controls="browseTab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Browse</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- Tab panes -->
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="uploadTab">upload Tab</div>
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="browseTab">browseTab</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```